# Vhdl How to make a simple addtion of binary with fixed point?

Tags: vhdl

I'm currently learning to code in vhdl and I want to make an addition (ex: 001011.110 + 001101.001) .

Comment: You have been a member for two years. You should know by now how to ask a question. Which this isn't.

Answer (score 0):

As long as your decimals match, you can go ahead and add them.  So in your case:

```
  001011.110   Decimal 11.75
+ 001101.001   Decimal 13.125
= 011000.111   Decimal 24.875
```

Make sure that you are doing sign-extension properly!